# Is Profile synchronization by using SharePoint AD Import supported for single server installation?

Tags: 2013, active-directory-import

Synchronize user and group profiles in SharePoint Server 2013

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049%28v=office.15%29.aspx) mentions that You must have a full installation of SQL Server, not the Express edition. Profile synchronization will not work if you have installed SharePoint Server 2013 by following the [instructions in Install SharePoint 2013 on a single server with a built-in database.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

However, we are setting up the [Profile synchronization by using SharePoint AD Import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

We would like to know if the profile sync using SP AD import is supported for single server installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your AD on the same server as SQL Server and SharePoint Server, then it's not supported by Microsoft. However, it's a common setup for a development environment and it does work well.

If you're setting up a production environment, then don't have the AD on the same server as SQL or SharePoint.

Comment: How about SQL Express that is mentioned in the post? My dev envs usually have an SQL Server versions :)

Comment: My dev setup has SP2013 and SQL on 1 machine and AD on another DC machine and the user profiles were successfully imported. So it Works this way..

Comment: @RobertLindgren If you succed inställning on SQL Express I think it works, but again, it's not supporter by MS :)

Comment: @NachiketKamat It works, but preferably you should consider moving the SQL Server to another Windows Server for performance reasons.

Comment: Yep, I think that is the big take away: it works, but is not supported :)

Comment: Hi, suppose we change the values of certain SharePoint user profile properties and the sync happens then will the property value get lost?